# How do I recreate this drum beat from Nu:Logic - The Sound Of Your Smile?

Tags: daw, replication, drum

I found this drum beat, that is extremely prevalent in electronic music and I would like to recreate it in my song. I am a beginner, so I am not sure how to pick out the individual drums and time them correctly in the DAW.

I am using LMMS and I am using the basic included drum sounds.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the first thing to note here is that the drum track you're hearing on this is most likely a sample. The sounds have a fairly distinctive quality that comes from being sped up from around 120bpm to around 160bpm (about a 33% increase in speed).

Recreating this is not impossible but, as this is a sample, you will need to think a little like a real drummer.

I attempted to rebuild this quickly using Garage Band. Here's the basic pattern:

[image: Drum pattern in piano roll]

You can see that the high hats are falling on every 16th note except for the last 8th which carries an open high hat. The kick is falling on beats 1 and 3 1/2 - this half-beat offset is what gives it that little jumping feeling halfway through the bar: you expect the beat on the 3 but it doesn't arrive until half a beat later.

The snare is more complex with the usual hits on 2 and 4 but with a couple of 'ghost' hits at 2 3/4 and 3 1/4 - these bring in that skipping feeling.

For some extra depth, I played with the velocities. The high hat alternates between 80 and 40 which sounded right with the drum sounds I was using. The point is to offer a little texture by simulating the difference between the drummer's right and left hands.

[image: High hat pattern in piano roll with velocities highlighted]

Similarly, with the snare, the regular hits have a velocity of 80 and the ghost hits are much lower at around 20. Again, this simulates the drummer dragging the stick onto the drum with their left hand.

[image: Snare pattern in piano roll with velocities highlighted]

These velocity settings sounded right for the sound I was using but may be different for you, so don't be afraid to play around with them.

And lastly, don't forget to tweak your sounds by pitching them up a little if possible - this will give them a similar feel to the sample used in the original track.